# how to count how many times a number is repeated and more than one column

Tags: mysql, sql

example::

```
JOHN       | 1   | 6  | 2
PETER      | 1   | 7  | 6
MARK       | 2   | 1  | 6
DIANNA     | 3   | 2  | 1
SPIDERMAN  | 4   | 1  | 6
JAMIE FOXX | 5   | 1  | 6
```

how can I do a select count how many times that the numbers are repeated in each of the 3 columns

Example:

- number 1 is repeated 6 times.
- the number 6 is repeated 5 times.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your number column  are c1,c2 and c3 and the table is t.

```
select      c,count(*)

from        (         select c1 as c from t 
            union all select c2      from t 
            union all select c3      from t 
            ) t

group by    c
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for 1

A way is using union and sum

```
select sum(num) from 
(
  select count(*)  as num
  from my_table 
  where col1 = 1
  union all
  select count(*) 
  from my_table 
  where col2 = 1
  union  all
  select count(*) 
  from my_table 
   where col3 = 1 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN col1 = @number THEN 1 END) + 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN col2 = @number THEN 1 END) +
       COUNT(CASE WHEN col3 = @number THEN 1 END) as repeat
FROM YourTable, (SELECT @number := 1) as parameter
```